# conditional xml requests

Tags: xml, conditional-statements

I am trying to get my website to request a product from a mysql database, but I have a flash animation displaying the product. This animation is controled by an xml file.

Is there any way to incorporate a similar thing as a $_REQUEST in php in xml? Because otherwise i have to create 100+ xml for each product which will take time.

So some more technical details;

I have a product details page: www.yoursite.com/product/product.php

With a embedded flash:

```
<div style="width:300px; height:330px; padding:10px; margin:0px 585px 0px 10px;">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var flashvars = {};
        var params = {};
        params.scale = "noscale";
        params.salign = "tl";
        params.wmode = "transparent";
        var attributes = {};
        swfobject.embedSWF("ImageBeforeandAfterFX.swf", "DivImageBeforeandAfterFX", "290", "320", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
    </script>
    <div id="DivImageBeforeandAfterFX">
        <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
            <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
        </a>
    </div>
```

And a image settings xml file (images.xml)

```
<photos>
<photo image="images/product_0001.png" colorboxImage="images/u4.png" colorboxInfo="" colorboxClass="image" url="http://web link" target="_blank"><![CDATA[<head>Reign Supreme</head><body>Drag line across to see the ball's core</body>]]></photo>
<photo image="images/product_c_0001.png" colorboxImage="images/u5.png" colorboxInfo="" colorboxClass="image" url="http://web link" target="_blank"><![CDATA[<head></head><body></body>]]></photo>
</photos>
```

What i want to do is for the 0001 (which is the id) to change depending on the product id which will be given in the server request. i.e.`www.yoursite.com/product/product.php?id=0001`  etc.

Comment: XML ist not a programming language. So, no. But your question is not complete anyway, you should add more technical details and there will be a way to do what you want.

Comment: So the server should deliver a 4-liner XML file like the one you show with nothing but the ID changed? Or do other attributes change based on the ID (paths etc)?

Comment: @Tomalak no just the id changes because the images folder is included in the directory

Comment: Well, if you think about it there is no reason to transfer an XML file over the wire (wasting bandwidth) if you already know exactly what the result will look like, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using PHP, you can generate XML dynamically in code, you don't need to create separate static files. Read the ID from the request, use it to query the DB, grab the values you need, and format a response string accordingly.

Comment: ok i'm extremely new to xml and php integration could you give me a heads up that would be great.

Comment: You need to create a separate PHP script (ie, getimagesxml.php) that you can pass a productid to, and have it return an XML string with the specified productid inserted where needed.  If you need to adjust other values of the XML based on the productid, the PHP script can do an database query as needed.  Then update your Flash animation to call the new PHP script instead of downloading an XML file directly.  It will still receive XML data, just XML that you generated dynamically.